# Making a Bootstrap 3 logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Expectation: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXtqY.png

I tried and the error is that everything is within the navbar

Please help-me a create a logo outside and inside of navbar

Comment: Copy the relevant part of the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to customise in **CSS**

CSS

```
.navbar-brand{
    height: auto;
  }
```

DEMO http://www.bootply.com/117177

Updated version

```
.navbar-brand{
    height: 411;
}
```

DEMO http://www.bootply.com/117647

Comment: Thanks, but not is... I want the logo skirt down without changing the navbar

Comment: @user3349163 you need to LOGO exactly same like the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/VXtqY.png ?

Comment: @user3349163 I have updated answer. accept answer if you like. I would suggest you use more technical words for future questions. All the best (y)

Comment: @user3349163 FYI - when your navbar is collapsed, the logo does NOT hang below the navbar, the navbar bottom aligns with the logo....not sure if you care though. Pretty cool though, nice work!